# Is it possible to use \nabla in the abbreviations?

Tags: symbols, acronyms

I am using `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}` for the list of abbreviations and I'd like to define the abbreviation `\acro{\nabla}{Volume of Displacement}` but the errorcounter rises from 4 to 39 with just that change.

It was possible to introduce the abbreviation with

```
\acrodef{vod}[$\nabla$]{Volume of displacement}
```

But then it wouldn't appear in the list of abbreviations.

Does anyone know something to make this work. Any unorthodox workaround would be OK as well!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing where `\acro{nabla}[$\nabla]{Volume ...}` causes an error?

Comment: "_the error counter rises from 4 to 39_": don't ignore those 4. Who knows what is going on...

Comment: Sorry, the 4 errors before are only warnings that certain fields in the bibliography entrys aren't filled.

\acro{nabla}[$\nabla]{Volume ...} does actually work as I wish it to... I always used \acro{short}{long} and using short as key instead of using a separate key.. So everything is fine now, thanks a lot

Comment: Please prepare a little code, starting at \documentclass, ending at \end{document}, with your package and abbrev. used, WHICH shows your problem after we compile it. Code is our currency, for very practical reasons. Thanks

Comment: To close voters: An MWE would be nice, but with the OPs comment there is enough to answer, there is a single question here so focus is fine.  This might be a dupe, but I've not been able to find anything suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\acro` supports the same optional second argument to specify a short form different to the acronym name as `\acrodef` so

```
\acro{nabla}[$\nabla]{Volume of displacement}
```

will work for the list.

[`acronym`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) (and similar packages) require some sort of macro-free text to identify and track the acronym internally (which is the argument used for `\ac` and co), often this is the same as the text-based short form, so an optional mechanism for specifying an alternative short form is made available.  For [`acronym`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) this is the optional second argument available to all of `\acro`, `\newacro` and `\acrodef`